# CSS Transition, how it works?

Tags: css

I have a simple code with CSS transition and image hover effect. 
[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/kriszap/pen/PpeRbL?editors=1100)

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    visibility:hidden;
    overflow:hidden;
```

Could you please explain to me:

1. Why this part causes left to right animation? (apparently "all" property)

   ```
   transition: all 0.2s ease;
   ```
2. How can I change it to make a simple fade instead of left/right move? Do I have to use jQuery for it?

Thanks
Kris

Comment: You don't need all these vendor prefixes.

Comment: meaning I can get rid of -moz- and -o- ? Will it still work in other browsers?

Comment: See http://shouldiprefix.com/#transitions.

Answer (score 2):

1. the left to right is because the position of
   `.item:hover .overlay` and `.item .overlay` are both 'left: 0;' if you change both to 'right: 0;' you get the animation from right to left
2. no Jquery is required for a fade effect, you could just add two css properties (opacity) opacity 0 on the `.item .overlay` and opacity 1 on the `.item:hover .overlay`

Comment: Ok I understand, and what about top - bottom animation?

Comment: @KrisZap then you have to change the with and height, note that the width in .item .overlay 0% is, if you change the width to 100% and the height to 0% you get a top to bottom effect

Comment: @KrisZap did you have any further questions ? Or have I answered them all?

Comment: thanks @goosmaster - I need to do some experiments in order to understand it fully :)

Comment: @KrisZap no problem, please consider selecting an answer

Answer (score 2):

Change your `CSS` to the following:

```
.item .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    top:0;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity:0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    overflow:hidden;

}
```

And on hover

```
.item:hover .overlay {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[Updated codepen demo](http://codepen.io/sanjeevks121/pen/RpyMEm?editors=1100)